# What is this rails server log error? (attached)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-log

As of 5 days ago, my rails server started spewing errors in my log to the point where I am getting Heroku L10 issues non-stop. I have no idea how to fix it since I don't understand the error message.

Anybody with suggestions?

```
WARNING: V8 isolate was forked, it can not be disposed and memory will not be reclaimed till the Ruby process exits.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/parallel-1.19.2/lib/parallel.rb:445: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f8521f109d0
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007f8581f73bd8 RBP: 0x00007f8569eb02d0 RSP: 0x00007f8569eb0250
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x00007f8521f10700 RCX: 0x0000000000000001
 RDX: 0x0000000000000000 RDI: 0x00007f8521f10700 RSI: 0x0000000000000000
  R8: 0x00000000000000ca  R9: 0x00007f8522f119d0 R10: 0x000000000000000d
 R11: 0x00007f85238693c0 R12: 0x00005640dd835740 R13: 0x00005640dd095a28
 R14: 0x00005640dd835750 R15: 0x00005640dd0959f0 EFL: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_bugreport+0x7ce) [0x7f8582a4402e] vm_dump.c:755
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_bug_for_fatal_signal+0xe7) [0x7f8582863207] error.c:658
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(sigsegv+0x4b) [0x7f85829a807b] signal.c:946
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(0x7f85823e5fd0) [0x7f85823e5fd0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(__GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex+0x28) [0x7f8581f73bd8]
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sq_mini_racer-0.2.5.0.1.beta3/lib/sq_mini_racer_extension.so(_ZN2v88platform12WorkerThreadD0Ev+0x1c) [0x7f85232b945c]
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sq_mini_racer-0.2.5.0.1.beta3/lib/sq_mini_racer_extension.so(0x7f85232b777e) [0x7f85232b777e]
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sq_mini_racer-0.2.5.0.1.beta3/lib/sq_mini_racer_extension.so(0x7f85232b666a) [0x7f85232b666a]
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sq_mini_racer-0.2.5.0.1.beta3/lib/sq_mini_racer_extension.so(0x7f85232b683e) [0x7f85232b683e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(0x7f85823ea0f1) [0x7f85823ea0f1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(0x431ea) [0x7f85823ea1ea]
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(ruby_stop+0x10) [0x7f8582870cc0] eval.c:290
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(ruby_run_node) (null):0
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_f_fork+0x74) [0x7f85829576e4] process.c:4130
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc_with_frame+0xc9) [0x7f8582a206ba] vm_insnhelper.c:2514
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc) vm_insnhelper.c:2539
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0x58) [0x7f8582a2bded] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:782
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c+0x15b) [0x7f8582a3527e] vm.c:1116
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_bh) vm.c:1134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield) vm.c:1179
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_0) vm_eval.c:1227
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_values2) vm_eval.c:1273
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(each_with_index_i+0x7d) [0x7f8582852b2d] enum.c:2365
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield_with_cfunc+0x115) [0x7f8582a28025] vm_insnhelper.c:3220
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_bh+0x2c) [0x7f8582a32f34] vm.c:1139
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield) vm.c:1179
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_0) vm_eval.c:1227
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_1) vm_eval.c:1233
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield) vm_eval.c:1243
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_array_len+0x0) [0x7f85827ce8ac] array.c:2135
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ary_each) array.c:2134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call0_cfunc_with_frame+0x10c) [0x7f8582a3656c] vm_eval.c:91
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call0_cfunc) vm_eval.c:105
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call0_body) vm_eval.c:140
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_call0+0xbf) [0x7f8582a36c1f] vm_eval.c:52
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_call_kw+0x6d) [0x7f8582a36ebd] vm_eval.c:268
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(iterate_method+0x39) [0x7f8582a37949] vm_eval.c:718
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_iterate0+0xd1) [0x7f8582a25211] vm_eval.c:1415
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_block_call+0x54) [0x7f8582a253c4] vm_eval.c:1480
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(enum_each_with_index+0x44) [0x7f858284bd04] enum.c:2395
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc_with_frame+0xc9) [0x7f8582a206ba] vm_insnhelper.c:2514
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc) vm_insnhelper.c:2539
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0x58) [0x7f8582a2bded] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:782
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c+0x98) [0x7f8582a32e0e] vm.c:1116
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_bh) vm.c:1134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield) vm.c:1179
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_0) vm_eval.c:1227
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_1) vm_eval.c:1233
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield) vm_eval.c:1243
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(each_slice_i+0x6f) [0x7f8582852a0f] enum.c:2517
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield_with_cfunc+0x115) [0x7f8582a28025] vm_insnhelper.c:3220
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_bh+0x2c) [0x7f8582a32f34] vm.c:1139
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield) vm.c:1179
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_0) vm_eval.c:1227
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_1) vm_eval.c:1233
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield) vm_eval.c:1243
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_array_len+0x0) [0x7f85827ce8ac] array.c:2135
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ary_each) array.c:2134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call0_cfunc_with_frame+0x10c) [0x7f8582a3656c] vm_eval.c:91
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call0_cfunc) vm_eval.c:105
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call0_body) vm_eval.c:140
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_call0+0xbf) [0x7f8582a36c1f] vm_eval.c:52
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_call_kw+0x6d) [0x7f8582a36ebd] vm_eval.c:268
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(iterate_method+0x39) [0x7f8582a37949] vm_eval.c:718
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_iterate0+0xd1) [0x7f8582a25211] vm_eval.c:1415
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_block_call+0x54) [0x7f8582a253c4] vm_eval.c:1480
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(enum_each_slice+0x9d) [0x7f858284b91d] enum.c:2579
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc_with_frame+0xc9) [0x7f8582a206ba] vm_insnhelper.c:2514
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc) vm_insnhelper.c:2539
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0x58) [0x7f8582a2bded] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:782
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c+0x98) [0x7f8582a32e0e] vm.c:1116
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_bh) vm.c:1134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield) vm.c:1179
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_0) vm_eval.c:1227
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_1) vm_eval.c:1233
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield) vm_eval.c:1243
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_array_len+0x0) [0x7f85827ce8ac] array.c:2135
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ary_each) array.c:2134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc_with_frame+0xc9) [0x7f8582a206ba] vm_insnhelper.c:2514
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc) vm_insnhelper.c:2539
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0x58) [0x7f8582a2bded] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:782
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c+0xa7) [0x7f8582a34c28] vm.c:1116
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_bh) vm.c:1134
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_yield) vm.c:1179
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_yield_0) vm_eval.c:1227
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(catch_i) vm_eval.c:2228
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_catch_protect+0xae) [0x7f8582a2567e] vm_eval.c:2310
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_catch_obj+0x2c) [0x7f8582a2577c] vm_eval.c:2336
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc_with_frame+0xc9) [0x7f8582a206ba] vm_insnhelper.c:2514
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_cfunc) vm_insnhelper.c:2539
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0x58) [0x7f8582a2bded] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:782
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ec_vm_ptr+0x0) [0x7f8582a35b3d] vm.c:1074
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_global_hooks) vm_core.h:1932
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1076
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c) vm.c:1119
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_proc) vm.c:1216
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1245
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_bmethod+0xac) [0x7f8582a3c42c] vm_insnhelper.c:2570
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0xa2) [0x7f8582a2bd36] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:801
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ec_vm_ptr+0x0) [0x7f8582a35b3d] vm.c:1074
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_global_hooks) vm_core.h:1932
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1076
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c) vm.c:1119
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_proc) vm.c:1216
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1245
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_bmethod+0xac) [0x7f8582a3c42c] vm_insnhelper.c:2570
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0xa2) [0x7f8582a2bd36] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:801
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0xab) [0x7f8582a3211b] vm.c:1920
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ec_vm_ptr+0x0) [0x7f8582a35b3d] vm.c:1074
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_global_hooks) vm_core.h:1932
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1076
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c) vm.c:1119
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_proc) vm.c:1216
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1245
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_bmethod+0xac) [0x7f8582a3c42c] vm_insnhelper.c:2570
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0xa2) [0x7f8582a2bd36] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:801
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x74f) [0x7f8582a327bf] vm.c:1929
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_ec_vm_ptr+0x0) [0x7f8582a35b3d] vm.c:1074
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_global_hooks) vm_core.h:1932
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1076
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c) vm.c:1119
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_proc) vm.c:1216
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_invoke_bmethod) vm.c:1245
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_call_bmethod+0xac) [0x7f8582a3c42c] vm_insnhelper.c:2570
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_sendish+0xa2) [0x7f8582a2bd36] vm_insnhelper.c:4023
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_exec_core) insns.def:801
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x74f) [0x7f8582a327bf] vm.c:1929
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_iseq_block_from_c+0x183) [0x7f8582a360e3] vm.c:1116
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(invoke_block_from_c_proc) vm.c:1216
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(vm_invoke_proc) vm.c:1238
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_vm_invoke_proc) vm.c:1259
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(thread_do_start+0x289) [0x7f85829ebd99] thread.c:697
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(thread_start_func_2+0x257) [0x7f85829ee117] thread.c:745
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(rb_native_cond_initialize+0x0) [0x7f85829ee74b] thread_pthread.c:969
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(register_cached_thread_and_wait) thread_pthread.c:1021
/app/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.7(thread_start_func_1) thread_pthread.c:976
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(0x76db) [0x7f8581f726db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7f85824c8a3f]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Process memory map:

150d77480000-150d77500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
17f601700000-17f601780000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
1926f3080000-1926f3100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
259cb9880000-259cb9881000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
278c9d400000-278c9d480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3164e3400000-3164e3480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3752d3c00000-3752d3c80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38cde2c80000-38cde2c9d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38fb691da000-38fb69200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
38fb69200000-38fb69201000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38fb69201000-38fb69202000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Comment: The seg fault is an indication of a bug in Ruby, so the question will be how to isolate and potentially work around it. Have you recently upgraded to 2.7 or added new gems to your environment?

Comment: Yes, I recently upgraded to ruby 2.7

Comment: The thing is my staging environment is not spewing errors though..

Comment: It's a threading issue -- likely only hit it under load.

Comment: @dbugger would you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: Blowing up in parallel.  Something is not handling thread safety well.  What is your app doing?

Comment: problem was sqreen gem https://rubygems.org/gems/sqreen